# Entity framework 6 Best way to query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, projection

Say I have the following model -

```
public class Folder
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public virtual List<Letter> Letters {get; set;
}

public class Letter
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public virtual list<Folder> Folders;

   // ... 
}
```

What query should I use to get all letters from a specific folder?

For instance if I want all the letters in folder with Id 1:

If I simply use `context.Folders.Find(1).Letters`, it gets me a List instead of an `IQueryable<Letter>`, and it gets me some data that is not useful for this specific case.

However if I use `context.Letters.Where(x => x.Folders.Any(f => f.Id == 1)`

I'm inefficiently iterating through all the Letters which seems bad.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, all more or less result in the same queries to database. For example: context.Folders.Where(c => c.Id == 1).SelectMany(c => c.Letters);

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks alot